# media query isn't working, using Classes to change display property

Tags: css, media

I have a simple media query that isn't working... here is my code:

In an external stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .logo_1000{display:none !important;}
    .logo_320{display:visible !important;}
}
```

Next, in the html of my PHP Header file I have two sets of Logo HTML, each in its own wrapper with one of the classes above:

```
<div class="logo_1000" style="margin: 0px auto 0px; width: 1000px; height:100px;">
    <div style="width:100%; height:100px; display:inline-block;"><img src="http://www.bangorchildcare.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logo-1000x100.png" width="1000" height="100" /></div>
</div>
<div class="logo_320" style="display:none; margin: 0px auto 0px; width: 100%; height:100px;">
    <div style="width:100%; height:100px; display:inline-block;"><img src="http://www.bangorchildcare.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logo-320-100.png" width="320" height="100" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `media query that isn't working`? How is it behaving? How do you expect it to behave?

Comment: Did you add a meta viewport to head? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Essentially, I've set two sets of Logo's for the site. each in its own wrapper.  In the external CSS file I have: @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .logo_1000{display:none !important;}
    .logo_320{display:visible !important;}
}

Comment: Then in the HTML itself, one Logo is wrapped in the element with class "logo_1000"  and the other in an element with class "logo_320"...  It is as if @media screen and (max-width:768px)  {}    is doing nothing.  Because, when I view the site on a mobile emulator, the class "logo_1000" is still visible,, and "logo_320"  display is still 'none'

Comment: Change `display:visible` to `display:inline-block`. `display:visible` is invalid css.

Comment: I Changed     display:visible to display:inline-block       still not working.  Something tells me that the media query isn't executing...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the browser will always use inline css over css defined by "" over external styles.
Maybe you want to use Chrome DevTools (F12), they will make your life much easier
[image: Chrome DevTools Screenshot of CSS rules]

Comment: He added `!important` to css, this will override inline css

Comment: Not true. `!important` supersedes inline.

Comment: actually it does not, apparently. I'd thought too, maybe it's because of the media-query

Comment: display:visible is incorrect... no such rule in css

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should be something like `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

there is value of `display` is not correct, there is no such a thing as `visible`, it should be something from the list defined to the property, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp for valid values.

Usually, if you hover your mouse over the yellow warning mark, it says what is wrong.

[image]

Comment: yes, this is true. but not the reason why the media query isnt executing valid css.... and this was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the display property of css.
The display property specifies the type of box used for an HTML element.
There is no such thing as `display: visible;`. 
Have a look in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

- **inline**   Default value. Displays an element as an inline element like span
- **block**    Displays an element as a block element like p
- **flex** Displays an element as an block-level flex container. New in CSS3
- **inline-block** Displays an element as an inline-level block container. The inside of this block is formatted as block-level box, and the element itself is formatted as an inline-level box
- **inline-flex**  Displays an element as an inline-level flex container. New in CSS3
- **inline-table** The element is displayed as an inline-level table
- **list-item**    Let the element behave like a li element
- **run-in**   Displays an element as either block or inline, depending on context
- **table**    Let the element behave like a table element
- **table-caption**    Let the element behave like a caption element
- **table-column-group**   Let the element behave like a colgroup element
- **table-header-group**   Let the element behave like a thead element
- **table-footer-group**   Let the element behave like a tfoot element
- **table-row-group**  Let the element behave like a tbody element
- **table-cell**   Let the element behave like a td element
- **table-column** Let the element behave like a col element
- **table-row**    Let the element behave like a tr element
- **none** The element will not be displayed at all (has no effect on
  layout)
- **initial**  Sets this property to its default value. Read about initial
- **inherit**  Inherits this property from its parent element.

Sample css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.logo_1000{display:none !important;}
.logo_320{display:block !important;}
}
```

Comment: I've corrected that.  display is now being set to 'inline-block'   yet still nothing happens.  I even tried changing the border color of the element, and that isn't "triggering" either.  Its as if the media query isn't executing.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

The problem was hiarchy of cascade rules.  The external style sheet where the media query resided could not over-ride the display properties set internally in the HTML document.  The solution was to move the internal css to the external style sheet, then show and hide the elements in the media query.  Like so:

```
/****LOGO*******************/
```

/***Fix for Mobile Phones***/
/***************************/

.logo_1000{display:inline-block;}/ * Show the default * /

.logo_320{display:none;} / * Hide the Mobile * /

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {  / *now we're on mobile, swap the logos * /

```
.logo_1000{display:none !important;}
.logo_320{display:inline-block !important;}
```

}